# "" ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy' ""

Tags: python-3.x

I can't seem to use a module in Jupyter notebooks that was successfully installed to my mac via pip3 install geopy.

I do not understand anything about working directory, where the module is being sent after download, or where jupyternotebooks is grabbing modules when you import them. Please help

```
import geopy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopy'
```

Comment: type `pip search geopy` and check if installed this module properly.

Comment: tornado-geopy (0.1.0)         - tornado-geopy is an asynchronous version of
                                the awesome geopy library.
geopy (1.20.0)                - Python Geocoding Toolbox
  INSTALLED: 1.20.0 (latest)
pivotal-geopy (1.0.0)         - Python Geocoding Toolbox
swisslandstats-geopy (0.6.1)  - Python for the land statistics datasets from
                                the SFSO

Comment: so use `import tornado-geopy` instead of `import geopy`.
Hope this will work.

Comment: No, couldn't make it work. import tornado-geopy produced a syntax error because of the dash. I tried other combinations of the words tornado geopy with import in front and they didn't work either.

Comment: when you can't find `geopy` in your pip installed modules list, try to install that modules using this commands: `pip install geopy` or if you don't have pip use `easy_install pip` to install pip.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use a particular package in a jupyter notebook you can use the following command in a `code cell` in a jupyter notebook.

```
!pip install geopy
```

In the next code cell you can try

```
import geopy
```

This will at the least ensure you have the package to use within the jupyter notebook.

You may want to read [this text](https://docs.python-guide.org/) for details on python and pip